# WordPress ACF Pro - Sometimes data is missing on front end, requires resave in admin

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm experiencing the same issue from time to time across a number of WordPress sites - so I figure it's worth starting a conversation as Google doesn't seem to have much to say about this.

In a number of sites, at differnt times, using ACF Pro, certain data seems to go missing from the front-end. Simply resaving the post in admin and then refreshing on the front-end resolves the display issue - per post.

As this is happening in hundreds of posts on a brand new site this time, it's worth seeing if anyone has had this - and what they've done to resolve it. Finding each post amongst thousands is going to be too much effort to hunt and resave each from the admin panel.

Comment: If a single resave is enough it means the data is actually there but not displayed. Do you use a caching plugin on those websites maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being in touch with the developer of the plugin, they pointed us to a caching plugin as being an issue. I haven't had any issues since disabling this caching.